# Putting an Image Gridview Delete Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have a simple Gridview with `AutogenerateDeleteButton`.

[image]

I want to put a an recycle bin instead of Delete Hyperlink Button.

For example like this: [image]

Every row has to have this image instead of Delete Hyperlink Button.

How can I do that?

This is a perfect example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is image url property of command field of every action

```
<asp:CommandField DeleteImageUrl="" />
```

Comment: @Muhammed you are right but when i do that showing delete button hyperlink and also delete image button like this picture. I want showing just image not Hyperlink http://i1102.hizliresim.com/2011/2/22/1862.jpg

Comment: Yes i try but it's showing image and also show Delete Hyperlink like this image http://i1102.hizliresim.com/2011/2/22/1862.jpg <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/images/DeleteButton.gif" />

Comment: set property of your gridview AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"

Comment: YES! That's result. Thank you very much.